# Why adding SQL Server user to "Perform volume maintenance tasks" improves the speed of database resizing so much?

Tags: sql-server, performance

If I want to create 5GB database with

```
CREATE DATABASE [test]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'test', FILENAME = N'E:\2012\test.mdf' , SIZE = 5529600KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test_log', FILENAME = N'E:\2012\test_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

it takes **1 minute** on my SSD.

But when I add SQL Server user to `Perform volume maintenance tasks`

[image]

it takes only **1-2 seconds**.

**Why is that? Can someone explain to me what are the reasons for this?**

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain why the downvotes??  This looks like a fine question to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's because of [**Instant File Initialization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver16).  In short, SQL Server can take advantage of this privilege for database data files (not transaction log files).  What this means is that SQL Server does *not* have to zero out the data file(s) when initializing.

**Without the "Perform volume maintenance tasks" privilege** granted to the SQL Service account, upon the database creation SQL Server needs to zero out "test.mdf" and "test_log.ldf".

**With the "Perform volume maintenance tasks" privilege** permission set, SQL Server only needs to zero out "test_log.ldf".  A significantly less overhead, therefore minimized duration for the `CREATE DATABASE` in your testing.

*References*
[How and Why to Enable Instant File Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization)
[Instant Initialization – What, Why and How?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/instant-initialization-what-why-and-how/)

Comment: this seam that is feature is awesome, but why the default for it is off ?

Answer (score 3):

This will not affect .ldf files (log files), at least not according to the MS Article

**Why do it?**  Speed

**Why NOT do it?**  Possible security risk.  Someone could hack into your box and possibly read the non-zero'd memory spaces and retrieve that data.  Small risk, but still a risk.  This is why it is not enabled by default.

Detailed explanation: [How and Why to Enable Instant File Initialization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2009/12/22/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization/)

Comment: Note to the reader: If you're concerned about people hacking into your server and reading old data from deleted file, leaving IFI off may be helpful, but it's hardly what I'd consider sufficient. And, if you've got software that overwrites deleted files already, then you'd probably be OK to turn IFI on, as that software should have already zeroed out the space.

Comment: There's now a checkbox during install (SQL 2016 onwards) to grant this right to the SQL Server service account so I guess MS are a little more relaxed on the security front too.